# Why am I getting the error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" when trying to iterate over a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on problem 19 of Project Euler and the method I'm trying at the moment involves iterating over some lists. However I am getting a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" on the line 'for j in daysInYear:'. I can't see what the problem is as the for loop should be iterating over the daysInYear list.

(P.S. If you are familiar with Project Euler I am not looking for advise or the answer for problem 19, just why this particular line of code isn't working)

```
leapYears = [*a list of integers*]
daysInYear = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

numberOfDays = 0
for i in range(1901,2001):
    if i not in leapYears:
        for j in daysInYear:
            numberOfDays += j
    else:
        for j in daysInYears:
            numberOfDays += j
            numberOfDays += 1
```

Comment: `for j in daysInYears:` should be `for j in daysInYear:`.

Comment: Well that's deeply embarrassing.

Comment: That variable doesn't make sense. Maybe days in month?